# AWS - Creating a Route53 subdomain in a separate account to the top level domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have two AWS accounts.  For a complicated set of reasons, my top level domain (let's called it my-domain.com) is registered in one account, but I'd like to be able to register preproduction.my-domain.com in the other account.  Is there a way to do this?  If so, how?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do so... Maybe you can try [Transferring a Domain to a Different AWS Account](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-transfer-between-aws-accounts.html)

Comment: Do you mean create a hosted zone for the sub domain?  If so, then all you need to do is create the subdomain in your new account and delegate it over.

Comment: I'm going to close this as a duplicate of [Can I have a Route53 subdomain in a different Hosted Zone?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35785273/1695906), because that solution works either in the same AWS account or across different AWS accounts.