# Is it OK to host subdomain and parent domain in different AWS accounts using route 53?

Tags: dns, amazon-route53, subdomain

We have a dev account and a prod account. Is it OK to have a hosted zone in route 53 '*.dev.company.com' in dev aws account and have different host zone '*.company.com' in the prod aws account ?

Route 53 doesn't seem to restrict any duplication of zones even within an account.  How do we avoid conflicts in a devops org where multiple members of the team are registering apps. And if hosted zones can be duplicated in two different accounts, a same fqdn record sets like 'myapp.subdomain.company.com' can be accidentally created in route 53 in two different accounts.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [Can I have a route53 subdomain in a different Hosted Zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35785273/1695906) ...  You can't accidentally create a 2nd **working** hosted zone in 2 different accounts (or two in the same account), since each time you create a hosted zone, 4 different Route 53 nameservers are assigned to the domain. Only those specific Route 53 servers will answer queries for *that* hosted zone, and the Internet will have no reason to query any of the others. Adding delegation NS records to the parent zone is what makes a subdomain work, regardless of account.

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, follow the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110490/cloud-computing-aws-azure-google-openstack-etc?referrer=Gtut7wQSWPk88jFJz_zqMg2) and up-vote some sample questions.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, that clarifies it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Why not.

If you have an existing domain and hosted zone, and you want to create subdomain records, you can do either of the following:

- Create the records you need inside the existing "example.com" hosted zone.
- Create a new hosted zone to hold the records associated with your subdomain, as well as a delegation set in the parent hosted zone that refers clients to the subdomain hosted zone.