# route 53 hosted zones NS values

Tags: routes, amazon-route53

Can I have multiple hosted zones active for Route 53...? Actually I have one domain name for example: example.com , But I have two hosted zones in different aws accounts for some dependencies.. How can I create a setup, that makes both hosted zones active...? Can I put the same NS values in both hosted zone's that are in my registered domain ...?

Comment: Unless you are using white label reusable delegation sets (and you are not, because if you were, you wouldn't be able to create more than one hosted zone for the same domain), you should never change the NS or SOA records in a Route 53 hosted zone.

Comment: Hello Micheal, Thanks for answering, so If i want to match the NS values that are in example.com hosted zone and domain name example.com, I have to change NS values in domain name right...? Btw my Registered domain is in aws, IS it a safe thing to edit and replace and NS values in the registered domain so that it matches my Route 53 hosted zone NS values...?

Comment: In the "registered domains" section of the console, use "add/edit nameservers" if it does not already contain the NS records from the hosted zone that you want to be autoritative.  Don't edit the NS records at the apex of the hosted zone itself.

Comment: See also [Can I Have a Route 53 Subdomain in a Different Hosted Zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35785273/1695906) This is the recommended way to delegate a subdomain to a different hosted zone, which can be in the same AWS account, or in a different AWS account.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple hosted zones active in multiple AWS Accounts for the same domain using Route53.

In this setup, one hosted zone is always authoritative which will first resolve any DNS queries. Here authoritative zone must explicitly delegate the desired subdomains to any other hosted zones which ideally would be scoped only to a single delegated subdomain each.

For example

- Lets say AccountA Hosted Zone is the authoritative zone for example.com.
- Then if you put a NS recordset for my.example.com in AccountA Hosted Zone to point to AccountB Hosted Zone for example.com.
- AccountB is only capable of configuring DNS recordset for my.example.com inside its hosted zone which takes effect may be to point to a A, CName or etc.

Comment: I think this answer could use some more detail... such as a clarification that one hosted zone is always authoritative -- they are not peers -- and the authoritative zone must explicitly delegate the desired subdomains to any other hosted zones, which ideally would be scoped only to a single delegated subdomain, each.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot . I have updated the answer with more information