# Multiple name servers for website and email

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, exchange-server, nameservers

I have my domain (mydomain) registered with ready space. I have added name servers for the domain from microsoft exchange which I use as my work email.

1. ns1.xxx.microsoftonline.com
2. ns2.xxx.microsoftonline.com
3. ns3.xxx.microsoftonline.com

I have also created a website for the same domain which is hosted on S3 using static website hosting.

I want www.mydomain.com to host this site. Hence I created a hosted zone in aws and added its name servers on readyspace (as done for ms exchange server).

After this emails to external emails started bouncing back. I want to know why this is happening and what is the proper way to configure this.

Thanks

Comment: You can't use multiple DNS hosts unless you have a way of synchronizing all of the records between them.  Doesn't nsx.xxx.microsoftonline.com provide a way to add resource records (e.g. a www CNAME record pointing to the bucket) to the records they are hosting for you?  Or provide you with the necessary records to create so you can use Route 53 exclusively?

Comment: I think it is possible to delegate a sub domain (www.mydomain.com) to a different name server.  See this qa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35778315/can-i-have-a-route53-subdomain-in-a-different-hosted-zone/35785273#35785273

Answer (score 1):

As far I can see there is a confusion on the DNS Records.

```
NS Records is for name servers
MX Records is for email servers
CNAME or A records is for rest of the servers
```

When you have updated NS records from Microsoft, rest of your records will change. Since you have moved all the records from any other name servers to Microsoft.

You can check all the above records such as,

http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/

Or you can use dns tools such as dig to go through your DNS records.

If your incoming email from other domains is not working, then problem could be on the MX records.