# Allowing IAM access to only a specific subdomain on Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-iam, amazon-route53

I need to give an IAM user Route 53 access to create records under a subdomain, say `data.example.com`. For example, the user should be able to create a CNAME for `server1.data.example.com`. At the same time, I don't want the user to be able to add/modify/delete any records other than `*.data.example.com`.

Is it possible to write a policy that does that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can restrict by hosted zone, but not by sub-domain. Your Route53 hosted zones should be split up by subdomain if you'd like to restrict to specific subdomains. You can [create a hosted zone for a subdomain](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-subdomain-route-53/):

#### For example if you wanted a subdomain named `test` you can do as the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35778315/can-i-have-a-route53-subdomain-in-a-different-hosted-zone/35785273#35785273) summarizes well:

> Create a hosted zone for test.example.com.
>
> Note the 4 name servers that Route 53 assigns to it the new hosted
>   zone.
>
> Back in the master zone, create a new resource record, with hostname
>   "test" using record type NS, and enter the 4 name servers that Route
>   53 assigned, in the box below.

The above delegates control of that subdomain to this new hosted zone, which has a unique zone id we can use in an IAM policy

#### You can then build an IAM policy that restricts actions to this zone:

```
{
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Action":[
            "route53:*"
         ],
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/<The new zone ID>"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Action":[
            "route53:ListHostedZones"
         ],
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Resource":[
            "*"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

From here you can tweak this policy to fit the actions you'd like the user to be able to take in this zone.

Answer (score 1):

From the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/access-control-overview.html)

In a policy, you can grant or deny access to the following resources by using * for the ARN:

- Health checks
- **Hosted zones**
- Reusable delegation sets
- Status of a resource record set change batch (API only)
- Traffic policies (traffic flow)
- Traffic policy instances (traffic flow)

Not all Route 53 resources support permissions. You can't grant or deny access to the following resources:

- **Domains**
- **Individual records**
- Namespaces (service discovery)
- Services (service discovery)
- Tags for domains
- Tags for health checks
- Tags for hosted zones

It basically means IAM finest grain control is individual hosted zone (DNS zone file).

You can create a hosted zone only for the particular subdomain by following this [AWS Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html)