# Add permissions to aws-cdk pipelines' cross account execution role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I do have three AWS accounts:

- Shared (Where the aws-cdk pipelines live)
- Development
- Production

The **Shared** account owns a route53 domain name with the corresponding zone.

I do want to allow **Development** and **Production** to be able to use those domain names (attach dns records, say `dev.domainname.com`)

**Edit: I need to access other resources (s3 buckets, certificatemanager, ...) in the shared account as well, this was a simplification for the sake of the question.**

I bootstrapped the accounts and cross account deployment of [pipeline stages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_pipelines.CdkStage.html) works as per this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/cdk/latest/guide/cdk_pipeline.html)

If I try to deploy a stack which uses the domain it fails as expected since the role (`cfn-exec-role`) in the **Development** stack has no permissions on the resources of the **Shared** Stack.

I could go and attach the necessary policies in the Shared Stack allowing the Roles in the **Development** and **Production** Stack access the the necesserary resource but is there any way to solve this in Code as per "Infrastructe as Code"?

This would require getting the execution roles of the **Development** and **Production** accounts and attaching permissions in the **Shared** Account

Comment: What do you mean by "execution roles" here?

Comment: cdk pipelines has two roles which are used to deploy a stack (created by the bootstrapping step) the deploying role (creating the resources) is the cfn-exec-role

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I assume you want something like this ([GitHub](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cross-account-cicd-pipeline)):
[image]
The main difference is that you don't want to manually create the roles in the prod/dev account and your dev-env is also in a different account.

I would extent this by creating a different CDK stack which creates the roles `CodePipelineCrossAccountRole` ([policy](https://cross-account-cicd-pipeline.workshop.aws/policies/update-cross-account-role.html)) and `CloudFormationDeploymentRole` ([policy](https://cross-account-cicd-pipeline.workshop.aws/policies/update-deployment-role.html)) on prod. In your case the same is also required for dev. Deploy these stacks in dev and prod and you can access the roles by their ARN in the pipeline-stack. And in an similar fashion you can extend this to give cross-account access to other shared resources as is already implemented for the artifact bucket en KMS.

Comment: I guess this is the right answer, maybe I will be able to provide an example, the manual part must be removed as this is error prone and not suitable for CI/CD, even if it is a one time action

Answer (score 4):

Because Route53 supports [cross-account subdomain Hosted Zones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35785273/1103511), you can avoid cross-account resource-sharing or permissions.  Create a `dev.domainname.com` Hosted Zone in your development account and a `domainname.com` Hosted Zone in your production account.

```js
const hostedZone = HostedZone.fromLookup(this, 'HostedZone', {
  // synth-time hosted zone lookup
  domainName: props.isProd ? 'domainname.com' : 'dev.domainname.com',
});
```

Comment: Okay, I guess this was oversimplified for my question as I have the issue for the root zone as well since there are a dozens of domains and also I need to use other resources like the certificate manager and s3 buckets. I need to solve this on a more generalistic level